# Why is the main page of PSE looking so weird in my Opera browser?

Tags: discussion, bug, design

Pictures would say better:

[image]

Then this; notice a large bar in the right part of the page; the conspicuous part is the appearance of hot questions at the bottom:

[image]

What is going on? I'm using Opera 30.0.1835.88; I then checked the Chem.SE page

[image]

It can be easily seen the ads are at their proper place; no grey bar present at the right part.

Even the meta PSE page is looking good:

[image]

Why is the main page looking so? I'm having no problem with the other SE sites. Can anyone please tell me what the issue is?

This [question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7159/site-sidebar-appears-below-content-in-google-chrome) also complains of the same problem but his browser is Chrome; I've also Chrome but there the main page looks good:(

Latest Update 1: Miracle!! I don't know how but the hot-questions list has come back to its original place!

[image]

But the fonts are still irregularly big & that grey side-bar is still there:(

---

Update 2: ****! Really no words to say :X It is in coma again;(

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue using Chrome for a while---it actually made me switch to Firefox.

Comment: @Danu: Is the problem permanent?

Comment: I didn't try to wait it out.

Comment: @Danu: I also've the Firefox but I always have comfort using Opera. It happened suddenly:( I don't know whether it is the browser's problem but other SE sites are all working good. Let me wait if some expert helps me sort out the issue. Fingers crossed!

Comment: What OS are you on? What version of Opera? Did you check to see if you happen to be zoomed in/out (`Ctrl + 0` resets the zoom)?

Comment: @Oded: Hi, sir, I'm using Windows 7 Professional & my browser is Opera 30.0.1835.88.

Comment: I've checked that at the very beginning; pressed `Ctrl+0` at the beginning to avoid any unwanted zooming but nothing happened.

Comment: OK, thanks. I see that with latest Opera, not sure why it renders so differently than Chrome (they use the same rendering engine).

Comment: So many long images....

Comment: @Kyle Kanos: Sorry for that; but I wanted to show each & every part of the page so that no one may tell I'm playing some prank only showing a part of the page of past.

Comment: What is the cause of the downvote? Should I not ask for what problem I am facing? It's ridiculous: just come & downvote without citing any reason:(